What movie about two brothers fleeing from their step father is this?
I saw this movie at a friend's place when I was a kid in the early 1990's, and thus my memory is a bit vague. List of recollections, not in order:

Two brothers are fleeing from their evil step father. 
I think they lived on a farm. 
There is one scene where they are fleeing from their step father and they have to cross a river while they are riding horses.
I seem to recall them being in a boat and there is a shark surrounding them. 
They escape into a cave which is hidden behind a water fall
One of their friends is killed by some evil men.

EDIT: I don't recall there being any cars or anything in the movie, I think it might be set in a very rural place or in the 1800's early 1900's perhaps.
Probably western television, and might be German as I saw it in Germany.
I never completed watching the entire movie.  

Do you remember, whether the film was coloured or black/white?

I do not remember. I would be surprised if it was not coloured.

Hi Improve! Do you remember what language the film was in?

There is Udaan a Hindi movie, with same plot!!

@akr Difficult to say. It should be available in german at least.

Brother and sister?

It's a bit of a long shot, but could it be Flight of The Doves (1971)?
There are only a couple of similarities, two orphan boys fleeing from their horrible uncle
But they leave from London to go to rural Ireland, which might explain the farm?
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0067104/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt
http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xfrzzb_flight-of-the-doves-starring-jack-wild-classic-film_shortfilms
I can't find any other clips of it, sorry.
And it may not be it anyway, but thought id try
